# Pivot Table giving me issues

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

So all I'm trying to do is make a pivot table based on data in another sheet. Nice, simple, easy.
Or so I thought. I did manage to actually have it work, but due to the nature of the whole scope of the macro, I had to clear my sheets and have all of my code run again.
The whole macro is meant to be a way for our logistics lady to simply put a file in a folder and run this program to extract the  needed data and make multiple pages with different data on it.

Long story short after awhile the macro would not make me any more pivot tables.
This is the code:

```
    Sub pivotTable()
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As pivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long


    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Ex33")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Master")


   'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

   'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="P1")


    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
     Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="P101")
```

After the line "Define Data Range", I get a Type mismatch (Error 13), and I am totally lost on how. It worked before, why isn't it now?
I even tried making a new sheet for the pivot table and still nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using Excel's Pivot Table?

Comment: How exactly do you mean? If you mean just manually then no I haven't. I was trying to make the tables build themselves.

Comment: You're calling `CreatePivotTable` twice...

Comment: I see that now. I fixed that but still no luck creating a table for some reason :(